# Obfuscator for dynamically generated JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, obfuscation

as per title I'm looking at a library that allows an ASP.NET MVC application to obfuscate dynamically generated JavaScript.
Please mind that I'm talking about actual obfuscation, rather than minification, as I'm trying to protect my content from scrapers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obfuscation isn't going to protect your content. It's trivial to deobfuscate most Javascript, and equally you can scrape content without needing to parse the source code.

Comment: 1. It's not gonna protect the content, but it's gonna be a deterrent. On top of that, if it's dynamic it's harder to see what's going on.
2. Sure, but who scrapes the content should have a javascript-executing scraper, and I know for sure that for now it's not the case

Comment: Lots of scrapers embed web browsers so they can pull text off your page whilst letting the browser engine do the work of executing your code. Obfuscating it will make it harder for someone to steal your source code, but the end result (the content) would be pretty simple to steal I would think.

Comment: It depends on the quality of the scrapers and on whether or not they're tailored for your site. If that happens the requests will pop out anyway and I'll block them, but I want to protect myself from guys scraping content matching certain patterns with random wget-like scripts and html parsers. Bottom line, I don't think you have a point and my needs are real, plus the question is valid regardless of the ultimate purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Try one of the online obfuscators: 
http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

Comment: +1 but: 1. weak and 2. can't afford the lag introduced by online obfuscation 3. the load on the poor site might be massive

Comment: I don't see the point of obfuscating javascript either. It will always be possible to reverse it.

Comment: Also I don't see the point about impeding performances as this obfuscation typcally happens when you deploy not on the fly (with a small batch program that obfuscates scripts before publishing).